# Why does "findViewById" return null in the oncreate method for android?

Tags: android

I've looked through the answers on stackoverflow for this newbie android question, but I cannot understand what the optimal solution is.

I am trying to create a simple activity (with a fragment) that has a couple of text fields and a button.  When the button is pressed, I would like the button to do something!

So I have my mainActivity class, along with its code fragment.  I am trying to correctly set the "onClickListener" to my button object.

When I do this in the "onCreate" method in the activity itself, it throws a nullpointerexception - I'm guessing this is because the button itself is not yet created.  However putting this code in the OnStart method would cause it to be called over and over again and seems out of place.

So I moved it to the "Placeholder fragment" - where it is no longer being reported as null, but I cannot use an intent to navigate to another page (because the other pages are not static AND I cannot reference the current activity using "this").

I'm pretty stuck and it seems like something simple.

Scenario #1: trying to initiate it in the OnCreate method (:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_made_my_day);

////////////////////// PROBLEM IS HERE //////////////////////////////////
    Button butLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_login);
    butLogin.setOnClickListener(butLogin_OnClickListener);

///////////

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Version 2 -- Fragment code, also doesn't work:

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_made_my_day, container, false);

        Button butLogin = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but_login);
        butLogin.setOnClickListener(butLogin_OnClickListener);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: post the fragment code, specifically the part about the intent that you can't use

Comment: Posting code fragment now, this is not a duplicate because I read other similar questions on stackoverflow before posting

Comment: Note: that in regard to the referenced question above this thread - it suggests moving the code to the "onCreateView" section - which I have already done and I am still having issues.  this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can reference the Activity from a Fragment (after it's been attached) by calling [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29). That should be enough to launch the intent. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityToCall.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Second, is the `but_login` Button actually in `activity_made_my_day.xml` or in `fragment_made_my_day.xml`? Depending on which, that's the place where you should use `findViewById()` (activity or fragment).

Comment: @rockit Ok, then your fragment code is correct. You should be able to use `getActivity().startActivity(intent)` in the click listener code.

Comment: When I am doing this, I am still getting the error that "mademyday cannot be referenced from a static context"  on the line "Intent intentSmileActivity = new Intent(MadeMyDay.this, SmileListActivity.class);" within the fragment

Comment: You just need a `Context` for the first parameter. Use `new Intent(getActivity(), SmileListActivity.class)`

Comment: OH!  Now I see.  Replace the mademyday with "getActivity()", that makes sense.  And it worked!  Thanks for explaining